# .htaccess Variables Issue Unrecognized header format %

Tags: apache, .htaccess, content-security-policy, mod-headers

I am building out a sort of Content Security Policy generator for one of my sites.   I am stumped by one particular section of the .htaccess portion of it

The generated .htaccess is:

```
# Media Sources
SetEnv CSP_Media "media-src 'self' ;"

# Default Sources
SetEnv CSP_Default "default-src 'self' kevinpirnie.com ;"

# Add the CSP Headers
SetEnv CSP "%{ENV:CSP_Default} %{ENV:CSP_Media}"
Header always set Content-Security-Policy %{ENV:CSP}
Header always set X-Content-Security-Policy %{ENV:CSP}
```

When I leave the quotes off the `SetEnv CSP` line, I get a different error: `SetEnv takes 1-2 arguments` which makes sense... but with the quotes around them, I am getting the `Unrecognized header format %` error

Any ideas what I can do to utilize variables for this, or how to fix the `header format` issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few issues here...

> ```
> SetEnv CSP "%{ENV:CSP_Default} %{ENV:CSP_Media}"
> ```

This actually sets the `CSP` environment variable to the literal value `%{ENV:CSP_Default} %{ENV:CSP_Media}` - the `CSP_Default` and `CSP_Media` env vars are not expanded. AFAIK there is no way to reference env vars in the value argument of the `SetEnv` directive.

You can use mod_rewrite (or `SetEnvIfExpr` - see below) instead to create this `CSP` env var that is the concatenation of two existing env vars, separated by a *space*.

HOWEVER, `SetEnv` (mod_env) is processed too late in the request for mod_rewrite (which is processed very early) to be able to read these env vars. So you will need to use `SetEnvIf` (mod_setenvif) instead (or use mod_rewrite as well to set the initial env vars).

For example:

```
RewriteEngine On

# Media Sources
SetEnvIf ^ ^ "CSP_Media=media-src 'self' ;"

# Default Sources
SetEnvIf ^ ^ "CSP_Default=default-src 'self' kevinpirnie.com ;"

# Add the CSP Headers
RewriteRule ^ - "[E=CSP:%{ENV:CSP_Media} %{ENV:CSP_Default}]"
```

Note the strategically placed double-quotes because the *value* argument contains *spaces*.

- `SetEnvIf` - the entire `name=value` pair in the `SetEnvIf` directive must be surrounded in double quotes (not the *value*).
- `RewriteRule` - the entire *flags* argument needs to be surrounded in double quotes (not the *value*).

**UPDATE:** You can avoid the use of mod_rewrite in the above and use the `SetEnvIfExpr` directive instead to concatenate the env vars using an [Apache expression](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/expr.html) (Apache 2.4).

For example:

```
# Add the CSP Headers
SetEnvIfExpr "reqenv('CSP_Media').' '.reqenv('CSP_Default') =~ /(.*)/" CSP=$1
```

The dots (`.`) on the LHS of the expression are string concatenation operators (much like PHP). They do not appear as part of the string captured by the regex (RHS) and used as the concatenated *value* in the `$1` backreference.

#### Accessing the env var in the `Header` directive

> ```
> Header always set Content-Security-Policy %{ENV:CSP}
> Header always set X-Content-Security-Policy %{ENV:CSP}
> ```

mod_headers uses a different syntax to access the value of env vars, hence the "Unrecognized header format %" error. You need to use `%{var}e` instead.

For example:

```
Header always set Content-Security-Policy %{CSP}e
Header always set X-Content-Security-Policy %{CSP}e
```

---

**Alternatively**, you can avoid mod_rewrite and mod_setenvif by not creating your intermediate `CSP` env var and just combine them in the `Header` directive.

For example:

```
# Media Sources
SetEnv CSP_Media "media-src 'self' ;"

# Default Sources
SetEnv CSP_Default "default-src 'self' kevinpirnie.com ;"

# Add the CSP Headers
Header always set Content-Security-Policy "%{CSP_Media}e %{CSP_Default}e"
Header always set X-Content-Security-Policy "%{CSP_Media}e %{CSP_Default}e"
```

Because of the *space*, the *value* argument needs to be surrounded in double quotes.

---

> I am building out a sort of Content Security Policy **generator** for one of my sites.

Although, if this code is "auto-generated"(?) then why not just generate the complete `Header` in a single step?

Comment: Thank you MrWhite.  I will look into all this in a few days... currently on a much needed PTO :)    To answer your last question though... for organizational purposes, and better legibility.   Eventually, I won't be the only one to have to look at the rules generated :)

Comment: That did indeed do the trick.  Thanks again

Comment: I've updated my answer to include an alternative method to using mod_rewrite to concatenate the two environment variables (to create the combined `CSP` env var). Since this can also be achieved by using `SetEnvIfExpr` (also part of mod_setenvif), although the syntax is arguably not as concise/readable.